# In a dictionnary, how to check that a key has exactly 1 value?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have this dictionnary:

```
{128: ['S', 'S', 'O', 'F'], 512: ['S', 'F']}
```

I would like to be sure that each key  has exactly one value 'F' and one value 'S' and return a message if it's not the case

I tried this but it didn't seem to work:
it didn't print the message

```
for key in d:
    if not re.search(r"[F]{1}","".join(d[key])) or not re.search(r"[S].{1}","".join(d[key])):
        print(f"There is no start or end stop for the line {key}.")
```

Thanks

Comment: It does not look like a regex question, you are checking if a string equals some value. Also, your keys are numbers, there are no letters.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary contain a list, not a string so you shouldn't use regex. You can check if the list contain exactly the number of values you want using `list.count(value)`.

```
for key in d:
  if not (d[ḱey].count('F') == 1 and d[ḱey].count('S') == 1):
    print(f"There is no start or end stop for the line {key}.")
```

Comment: 'i' is not defined here!

Comment: I took that part of code from who made the question

Comment: The question was edited, now it's `key` instead of `i`.  To avoid confusion you should make the same change.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the count of those characters in each value. One approach is below

```
sample = {128: ['S', 'S', 'O', 'F'], 512: ['S', 'F']}
wrong_lines = [index for index, value in sample.items() if value.count('S') == value.count('F') == 1]
print(f"Wrong lines {wrong_lines}")
```

Comment: This code return: **Wrong lines [512]**, which is not!

Comment: it returns the key of the wrong list!

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {128: ['S', 'S', 'O', 'F'], 512: ['S', 'F']}

for key in d:
  if not (d[key].count('F') == 1 and d[key].count('S') == 1):
    print(f"There is no start or end stop for the line {key}.")
```

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of the code from [@riquefr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70081334/3025856), posted a couple days ago, except that you included less explanation. Please review existing answers before contributing a new one. It is nice that you included sample data, but the function itself appears to be an exact copy. If I'm missing something, others will too: In that case, edit your answer to explain what differentiates your approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Counter and get the counts of all letters simultaneously:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> di={128: ['S', 'S', 'O', 'F'], 512: ['S', 'F']}
>>> {k:Counter(v) for k,v in di.items()}
{128: Counter({'S': 2, 'O': 1, 'F': 1}), 512: Counter({'S': 1, 'F': 1})}
```